# change TokenRange on Scylla

Tags: scylla

I have a keyspace `nba` with replication factor 2 (I know, it should be 3 but I cannot change it currently).

My scylla DB is 3 nodes (P1, P2 and P3).

I did `nodetool describering nba` and saw that each tokenRange is either written on P3 or replicated on P3. Therefore, my node P3 contains every data, is full and cannot run anymore.
(both `decribering` and the check of the size confirm that)

Is there a way to change that distribution and get a more even one?

---

**EDIT** : Yes, I changed my RF from 3 to 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a replication factor of 2 each node holds two thirds of the data. Double check your findings.

Comment: In theory, I totally agree. But both `describering` and the check of the size of the disk confirm that the distribution is not even among the clusters. Any idea how I can fix that ?

Comment: Try `SELECT TOKEN(your primary key), your primary key FROM your table` to see if some tokens are over-represented. Do you have very large partitions that dominate everything else?

Comment: Did you change RF? If so you should run `nodetool cleanup`

Comment: Yes, I changed it. I'm gonna try this cmd ASAP. Thx for the hint.

Comment: the cleanup fixed my problem !